# Flutter, What is different between onPressed: () {...}. and onPressed: methodCall()

Tags: flutter, audio-service

I am working on audio_service example.

and I seems, auidoHandler.play or pause ..else  callings work only like below

```
onPressed: auidoHandler.play
```

not like

```
onPressed : () -> {auidoHandler.play}
```

I did not have time to learn about dart or flutter but i have to do.

Plese enlight me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPressed` needs to get provided a reference to a function. `auidoHandler.play` is a function thus it can be used.

`() -> {auidoHandler.play}` is also a function but a function that does nothing because its missing the function call operator `()` at the end.

It should be `() -> {auidoHandler.play();}`

**Note:**
The option stated in the title of your question `onPressed: methodCall()` would not work because the methodCall() would call the function when the component is mounted and the result whould be passed as the function to be called on the event. Unless the function returns another function this would not work.

Comment: Why Google allow us to use 'play' with out (); ? Don't u think it must be a error?

Comment: I agree. I didn't know it allowed that. As far as type checking goes I think flutter can't know that is invalid because both are functions and I think both return null. But I think `auidoHandler.play;` should not be a valid statement. I don't know under what conditions it could be used like that.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
onPressed: auidoHandler.play,
```

is equivalent to

```dart
onPressed: () {
  auidoHandler.play();
},
```

or

```dart
onPressed: () => auidoHandler.play(),
```

In fact, the first version is preferred by the linter (see [`unnecessary_lambdas`](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#unnecessary_lambdas)).

---

Your issue is that you are not calling the method `auidoHandler.play` in your second example:

Replace

```dart
onPressed : () -> {auidoHandler.play}
```

with

```dart
onPressed: () {
  auidoHandler.play();
},
```

or

```dart
onPressed: () => auidoHandler.play(),
```